# Typescript union object types to interface type

Tags: typescript

I want to convert TypeScript union object types into interface type:

```js
type ActionTypes = { action: 'A', data: number }
| { action: 'B', data: string }
| { action: 'C' }

// to: { A: number, B: string, C: undefined or never ? }
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHYBVwQM5QLxQDeUAhgiqgFxQDkMNANFACYnAnWoCuAtgEYQATlAC+AKAA+RUuTTUaAIUYs2HKNmCDEqAOajJ0skjm0AwjX1jQkWLNTYAPDCgQAHsAipmueMYxZsAD58aQBtAGkobVhQmiMKGgBdROoACji7CykaVnYaAEoXd09vKABrCBBkADNYKAB+GJzVJKhqLi8Iau0IZktraF8KbEwbAiG0Rwn-SCCxAHp52z8RrHxg4hhOXgFBJgVqDS1dJlN2zu7UXqhkYSuANyEGyyA)

Comment: If your question is #1, then does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mL3JkN) meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help, my problem has been solved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [key remapping via `as`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to iterate over the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) members of `ActionTypes` and pull out the `action` prop as a key and the `data` prop as a value (if it exists).  Like this:

```
type Actions<T extends { action: string, data?: any }> = {
  [U in T as U["action"]]: "data" extends keyof U ? U["data"] : UndefinedOrNever
}
```

(I don't know whether you want `undefined` or `never` so just define `UndefinedOrNever` to be what you want).  Let's test it out:

```
type ActionTypes = { action: 'A', data: number }
  | { action: 'B', data: string }
  | { action: 'C' }

type ActionsType = Actions<ActionTypes>

/* type ActionsType = {
    A: number;
    B: string;
    C: UndefinedOrNever;
} */
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&module=7&ts=4.9.5#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIFUB2ATaAzAlo6yDyAnAOWgDdp9YBeWbM-AbhAhlgEEBjUDAe0QGcAPABVY0AB6hoKPrADesAIaceiAFyw+ofFgDmAGljIFoBQH51CxOFgBfAHxU5wWLADa8WFlgiFM+K4AiJS5eAIBdMPUAoxMA0QkpZBkAa2hwbjQEWFMEQJiFcNh1JFRMbDwiUnJgGyYoOA4QxCF6mWp5YJV1AHJWboN89UQAVwBbACNyW2dYAB85RWVeHoAhfsNjBXVNbUQdaZd5jqW1WG6AYW7p5gaTvhaWakaVQWfeB+g+OxAAegAqWA3Nh3D6OWQzFysIZjSYMCGwFbbLS6RguFznIZVOE2WB-H5AA)